# Txt into dataframe with near-empty columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the open-source financial statements data available from the SEC: https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets.html

I plan to try mathematical modelling on these merged with other data I have. Before I can, I need to generate a single large data-frame combining all the info from the `num.txt` from each quarter.

The first step would be to read an individual `num.txt` (from any one quarter) as a pandas df. The problem is that the column `footnotes` is usually blank, `coreg` is usually blank (but not always), etc. (without any explicit sign-posting as far as I can tell--but please, see for yourself at the website!). Can anyone help me to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use tab as the delimiter. FWIW, I read one of the files and it's over 3 million rows. So you're most likely not going to be able to combine more than a few of them with pd.concat() before you run into memory errors. There are probably other ways to do your analysis, but if you must have one very large table you could use a dask dataframe https://examples.dask.org/dataframe.html.

```
df = pd.read_csv('num.txt', sep='\t')

print (df.head(5)) 

    adsh                    tag                         version    coreg ddate     qtrs uom value          footnote
0   0000070502-20-000004    DerivativeNotionalAmount    invest/2013 NaN 20191130    0   USD 1.043574e+10    NaN
1   0000070502-20-000004    DerivativeNotionalAmount    invest/2013 NaN 20190531    0   USD 1.084328e+10    NaN
2   0000080424-20-000017    DerivativeNotionalAmount    invest/2013 NaN 20190630    0   USD 1.730900e+10    NaN
3   0000080424-20-000017    DerivativeNotionalAmount    invest/2013 NaN 20191231    0   USD 1.618200e+10    NaN
4   0000038777-20-000011    DerivativeNotionalAmount    invest/2013 NaN 20191231    0   USD 6.000000e+07    NaN
```